# AWS Secrets Manager: Credentials Error: Missing Credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to hide my API key to make a POST request to the API in my React App, using AWS Secrets Manager. However, I am running into this error: [Error Message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSg8m.jpg)

I tried adding an IAM policy to the IAM role and IAM user used to authenticate the user at login, however it is still not working.

**This is where I call the Secrets Manager to get the secret value:**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

```
const client = new AWS.SecretsManager({region: "us-east-2"});
```

```
async function getSecretValue(secret_name){
```

```
try {
    const data = await client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: secret_name  }).promise();
    const secretValue = data.SecretString || Buffer.from(data.SecretBinary, 'base64').toString();
    console.log(secretValue);} 
catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}};
```

```
module.exports = {getSecretValue};
```

**This is where I call the function:**

```
        const secretValue = getSecretValue('secret_key_name');
        console.log(secretValue);

        const requestConfig = {
            headers: {
                'x-api-key': secretValue
            }   
        }
```

**This is the solution i tried to implement to fix the Missing Credentials error:**
json

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:secret:SECRET_NAME"
    }
  ]
}
```

"ACCOUNT_ID", and "SECRET_NAME" with the appropriate values for your AWS account and the secret you want to grant access to.

Attach the policy to the appropriate IAM role or user

Can someone please direct me in the right direction? I have seen other solutions where IAM policies do not need to be used.

Comment: I would suggest adding the error as text in the question instead of adding it as a screenshot, text is more readable.